# Adding a column to a dataframe in R when result has been generated by a tapply formula

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R that looks like this

```
head(df)

Scoresheet.Id Entry.Number  Round   Judge.Name Judge.Initials Raw.Score
1        264372           608 2 Allen              ag        79
2        266552          2493 2 Allen              ag        67
3        265218          1996 1 Allen              ag        65
4        266554          2751 2 Allen              ag        64
5        266551          2399 2 Allen              ag        63
6        262825           113 1 Allen              ag        62
```

Obviously there's many more judges.

I'm trying to create a new column in the dataframe with a Z-score.  I'm able to calculate the Z-score based on each judge's raw scores using.

```
with(df, tapply(as.numeric(df$Raw.Score), df$Judge.Name, scale))
```

That yields an array.

How can I put the resulting Z-scores in a new column in the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Easy to do with `data.table`, avoiding the `tapply` completely.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, Zscore := scale(Raw.Score), by = Judge.Name]

   Scoresheet.Id Entry.Number Round Judge.Name Judge.Initials Raw.Score      Zscore
1:        264372          608     2      Allen             ag        79  1.96320316
2:        266552         2493     2      Allen             ag        67  0.05305954
3:        265218         1996     1      Allen             ag        65 -0.26529772
4:        266554         2751     2      Allen             ag        64 -0.42447636
5:        266551         2399     2      Allen             ag        63 -0.58365499
6:        262825          113     1      Allen             ag        62 -0.74283363
```

If you're trying to avoid adding package dependencies, try `aggregate`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$Zscore <- unlist(aggregate(Raw.Score ~ Judge.Name, df, FUN = "scale"))[-1]
```

Comment: This seems to work.  Might be nice to not have an additional dependency, but it's clean for sure.

Comment: I use `data.table` so much, I don't think of it as an additional dependency.

Comment: Fair enough ... whatever gets the job done ;-)

Comment: Added an option using `aggregate` which lets you bypass `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

```
z_scores <- with(df, tapply(as.numeric(df$Raw.Score), df$Judge.Name, scale))
```

Then just bind the Z scores to the df:

```
cbind(df, z_scores[[1]][, 1])
```

And voila.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  The length of z_scores is 85 which is equal to the number to judges.  The cbind step returns `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 11764, 85`

Comment: My bad, agf1997. I was actually getting a slightly different error message than you though, interestingly. Made an edit that should do the trick. :)

Comment: Now it's `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 11764, 24`

Comment: Interesting. I'm not getting that message. :/

Comment: Does it require the same number scores per judge?  Each judge has a different number of scores.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same result as Eric Watt. And just using the exact same with() function as the OP.